# C# Update elapse time while doing work on the main UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have the following code updates a label with the elapsed time in a background thread.  I would like this to continue when doing a lot of work on the main UI thread which is simulated by pressing the button.  I would like to keep the UI busy so users cannot complete another action.  How can this be done?

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private BackgroundWorker _worker;

        Stopwatch _watch = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitWorker();
            _watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }

        private void InitWorker()
        {
            if (_worker != null)
            {
                _worker.Dispose();
            }

            _worker = new BackgroundWorker
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true,
                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
            };
            _worker.DoWork += DoWork;
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }


        void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (_watch != null)
            {
                label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    label1.Text = _watch.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                });

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                double a = 600000000000000.5;
                a = a / 4.54;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy solution to block a user from doing something in WinForms is to use a FormDialog, which will take over the application until it's hidden or closed. In this case, when the button is pressed, just someForm.ShowDialog() insetad of someForm.Show() (modal vs modeless) and just unhide the Close button once the bgw worker is done.

Comment: SpaceSteak's idea is likely the way that you want to go.  Another option is to simply disable whatever buttons/controls you don't want the user to be using while you do your work.

Comment: SpaceSteak, not sure if this is the solution because in my case the work done when the button is pressed is also using the GUI to print stuff in an output window.  My application is 2 tree views where I drag and drop between them (work being done and printing to the output window) + a label with a timer that shows the elapse time while the work is being done.

Comment: Bottom line is you can't use the UI to do a long running process because everything will freeze - even updates. So that code in your button1_click will need to go into an async Task

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are blocking the UI thread the UI is frozen an no Invoke's can be processed (how could they? They marshal code to the UI thread which is busy).

This strategy is not working.

If you want to block the UI, don't freeze it. You probably should disable all input elements that you care about. A radical solution would be to overlay a transparent panel over the entire client area of the form. That's weird for the user, though.

In case you're not aware: You can easily run expensive work on a background thread using `await Task.Run(...);`. `BackgroundWorker` is obsolete.

Comment: A less radical solution would be to cut and paste the controls on to a panel and then disable the panel...

Comment: Yeah, good suggestion. I usually create a central method that I can use to dis- and enable all relevant controls.